# How to reference the maker in Google Maps Android API?

Tags: android-activity, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use Google Maps Android API to develop the GPS vehicle management APP.
In my app,I need to control the MarkerOptions in Googlemap class.
By I can't find the method like "removeMarkerByXX" in googlemap class.Or the method to reference the marker I have been added like "getMarkerByxxxx".

Only the addMarker() and the clear() methods is valid, but not enough in my case.
So,what should I do for add,remove,modify the makers in google map?

Answer (score 1):

Well,I know how to do now.

```
public Map<String,Marker> makerMap=new HashMap<String,Marker>();

MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(position.la, position.lo)).title(temptitle);//make a markeroption

Marker maker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);//make reference

makerMap.put(key, maker);//add to hashMap

makerMap.get(carno).remove();//remove from map

makerMap.remove(carno);// remove from hashMap
```